# MySQL 8 InnoDB - Partition function not allowed

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, partitioning

I am trying to partition a table with 300M+ rows. Data consists out of 15 months where I only need the last 6 months on a regular basis and once in a while the last 13 months.

To increase the query speed for the 6 month query I came up with the following partition command:

```
ALTER TABLE my_db.my_table
 PARTITION BY RANGE (DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y%m')) (
    PARTITION 2021_H1 VALUES LESS THAN (202107),
    PARTITION 2021_H2 VALUES LESS THAN (202201),
    PARTITION 2022_H1 VALUES LESS THAN (202207),
    PARTITION current VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
 ) ;
```

In return I get:

```
[HY000][1564] This partition function is not allowed
```

What's the issue here?

Comment: No that seems not to be the problem. I changed "current" to 2022H2 and also removed the _ and also tried just 2 partitions. Nothing worked.

Comment: Do not use DATE_FORMAT, use immediate value.

Comment: What benefit do you hope for in Partitioning?  It is good for dropping "old" data, but not much else.

Comment: Tables are growing by 3M sets per day and the SaaS application only needs last max 6 months, a computing one last 13 months. The goal is speed. Server has 128G RAM with InnoDB-Buffer 96G now filling up.

Comment: @RickJames After partitioning the performance is still bad, in total the pysical files of the DB have 120G while innodb_buffer_pool_size is 90G. I was hoping that partitioning would fix it. The entire table has 750M+ rows. Any ideas how to speed up performance?

Comment: Your partitions are rather large, and therefore can have little effect. I would, at least, make a partition for each month, perhaps even for each week. Whether this has an effect also heavily depends on the queries you perform. If you pick out data specifically from one or two partitions it can help a lot, but if you try grab half a year's data then it doesn't help at all.

Comment: Show us the main queries that are slow.  Also show us the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  From those we can help devise a way to improve performance.  "Partitioning does in inherently provide performance".

Answer (score 2):

Just as the error message implies, not every function is allowed as partition function. Try using `to_days`:

```
ALTER TABLE my_db.my_table
 PARTITION BY RANGE (to_days(`date`)) (
    PARTITION 2021_H1 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2021-07-01')),
    PARTITION 2021_H2 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2022-01-01')),
    PARTITION 2022_H1 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2022-07-01')),
    PARTITION current VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
 ) ;
```

Note:Should you come across `Error Code: 1503. A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function`, make sure you make a compound primary key based on your original PK and the `date` column. That's mandatory if you have a PK in your table when defining partions in MySQL.
Caution: **Foreign keys** are **NOT** supported for partitioned InnoDB tables. So please make sure you do not have them in the first place before making an partitioning attempt.

Comment: Actually something similar was returned: [HY000][1506] Foreign keys are not yet supported in conjunction with partitioning. That suggests that the table is not allowed to contain any foreign keys? There are currently 2 set for two other fields (not the date field).

Comment: Do you have FOREIGN KEYS in your table? Unfortunately I'm afraid they are not supported in PARTITIONed tables.

Comment: I've added that as a caution so that hopefully users who read it won't try it if they have an FK in the table to be partitioned.

Comment: I'm sorry for your loss.

Comment: I understand. For testing purposes, I deleted the FKs and am currently executing the partition command. It is running, curious if this will increase performance significantly.

Comment: @merlin - "2 set for two other fields" -- Please provide specifics.

Comment: @merlin - "increase performance significantly" -- very unlikely to provide any performance.  Only certain WHERE clauses benefit.  Also, `INDEXes` usually need to change when adding `PARTITIONing`; I done see any changes in that area.

Answer (score -1):

```sql
ALTER TABLE my_db.my_table
 PARTITION BY RANGE (`date`) (
    PARTITION 2021_H1 VALUES LESS THAN (20210701),
    PARTITION 2021_H2 VALUES LESS THAN (20220101),
    PARTITION 2022_H1 VALUES LESS THAN (20220701),
    PARTITION current VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
 ) ;
```

Comment: @KIKOSoftware The absence of the backticks is not a source of OP issue (but they'd be used for to prevent the further problem after initial issue fixing). I recommend not to use a function which can be read in the comment to OP.

Comment: Well, that isn't clear from your answer. This is exactly why you should put an explanation in your answer.

Comment: Will the numeric `20210701`?  I've always seen it as a DATE: `'2021-07-01'`.

Comment: @RickJames No - in general. Yes - in date context. See "DATE literals".